# awk command or sed command

Tags: awk, sed

```
000Bxxxxx111118064085vxas - header 
10000000001000000000053009-000000000053009-
10000000005000000000000000+000000000000000+
10000000030000000004025404-000000004025404-
10000000039000000000004930-000000000004930-
10000000088000005417665901-000005417665901-
90000060883328364801913 - trailer
```

In the above file we have header and trailer and the records which start with 1 is the detail record
in the detail record,want to sum the values starting from position 28 till 44 including the sign using awk/sed command

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output and also show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: wan to sum up the field in a specific output file

Comment: or to an output file

Comment: Also, why only awk/sed?

Comment: cat Axxxx.dat | grep ^1 | awk '{ print substr($1, 28, 16)}' > Axxxx.dat.endbalance

Comment: Can the first `+/-` sign be different from the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` we can solve this problem making use of [`substr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13):

> **`substr(s, m[, n  ])`:**
>   Return the at most `n`-character substring of `s` that begins at position `m`, numbering from 1. If `n` is omitted, or if `n` specifies more characters than are left in the string, the length of the substring shall be limited by the length of the string `s`.

This allows us to take the string which represents the number. Here, I assumed that the sign before and after the number is same and thus the sign of the number :

```
$ echo "10000000001000000000053009-000000000053009-" \
  | awk '{print length($0); print substr($0,27,43-27)}'
43
-000000000053009
```

Since `awk` implicitly converts strings to numbers if you do numeric operations on them we can write the following `awk`-code to achieve the requested :

```
$ awk '/header|trailer/{next}
       {s+=substr($0,27,43-27)}
       END{print s}' file.dat
-5421749244
```

Or in a single line:

```
$ awk '/header|trailer/{next}{s+=substr($0,27,43-27)} END{print s}' file.dat
-5421749244
```

The above examples just work on the example file given by the OP. However, if you have a file containing multiple blocks with `header` and `trailer` and you only want to use the text inside these blocks (exclude everything outside of the blocks), then you should handle it a bit differently :

```
$ awk '/header/{s=0;c=1;next}
       /trailer/{S+=s;c=0;next}
       c{s+=substr($0,27,43-27)}
       END{print S}' file.dat
```

Here we do the following:

- If a line with `header` is found, reset the block sum `s` to `ZERO` and set `c=1` indicating that we take the next lines into account
- If a line with `trailer` is found, add the block sum `s` to the overall sum `S` and set `c=0` indicating to ignore the lines.
- If `c/=0` compute the block sum `s`
- At the `END`, print the total sum `S`

Comment: Thanks, but the data which i shown is in a file  and am new to this awk so need help to subsitude the file in it.

Comment: replace `<FILE>` with the filename and this should do. Remark that this assumes only a single block `header,trailer`

Comment: cat file1.dat | '/header|trailer/{next}{s+=substr($0,27,44-28)}END{print s}' file1.dat.sumbal

Comment: for a sample file as mentioned above but when i used the real file which consisted of 609655 records it displays a zero....

Comment: is it any record count restrication is there when we use these awk commands ?

Comment: the 0 was correct infact the summation was zero thanks

Comment: just want to know how this was working substr($0,27,44-28) or in other words what each position.

Comment: likewise if i want to sum the value in the file from 12 to 27 is the Following awk '/header|trailer/{next}{s+=substr($0,11,27-12)} END{print s}' file.dat would yield me the result.

Comment: @user9794957 I have added various explanations to the text. I hope it answers most of your questions.

Comment: @user9794957 I'm happy it helped you out. If you like this answer, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: awk '/header|trailer/{next}{s+=substr($0,27,43-27)} END{print s}' file.dat this commands work fine but in this case the sign of the value is at the end  so the actual start of the field is 28 and sign comes behind at the position of 43 do you have suggestion to sum these number if the sign come at the end

Answer (score 1):

Here is sed, with help from bc to do the arithmetic:

```
sed -rn '
    /header|trailer/! {
        s/[[:digit:]]*[+-]([[:digit:]]+)([+-])$/\2\1/
        H
    }
    $ {
        x
        s/\n//gp
    }
' file | bc
```

I assume the `+/-` sign follows the number.